# conflict betwen dplyr and progress bar (shinyIncubator)

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I want to introduce a dplyr code into my shiny app, but I have experienced a problem already at the stage of loading the dplyr package. Even before I add any actual dplyr code and as soon as I add the line:

```
library(dplyr)
```

the following error is shown instead of one of the reactive inputs:

```
Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘n’, should be from class “numeric” or a subclass (was class “environment”)
```

This error appears only upon adding "library(dplyr)" to the code and does not appear any more if the code for progress bar is deleted. The error appears only instead of the input whose properties are reactive and are controlled through server.R. Another input remains intact.

Could please somebody indicate what is wrong? Thanks!

**server.R (does NOT work):**

```
library(shinyIncubator)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$new_input<-renderUI({ 
  if (is.null(input$input_file)) {
    return(NULL)
}

progress <- Progress$new(session, min=1, max=10)
on.exit(progress$close())
progress$set(message = 'Calculating',
             detail = 'Please wait...')
for (i in 1:10) {
  progress$set(value = i)
  Sys.sleep(0.05)
}

library(gdata)
dat<-read.xls(input$input_file$datapath,check.names=F)
selectInput("a",dat[1,1],c("b"="b","c"="c"))

  })  
})
```

**server.R (works properly):**

```
library(shinyIncubator)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$new_input<-renderUI({ 
  if (is.null(input$input_file)) {
    return(NULL)
}

#    progress <- Progress$new(session, min=1, max=10)
#    on.exit(progress$close())
#    progress$set(message = 'Calculating',
#                 detail = 'Please wait...')
#    for (i in 1:10) {
#      progress$set(value = i)
#      Sys.sleep(0.05)
#    }

library(gdata)
dat<-read.xls(input$input_file$datapath,check.names=F)
selectInput("a",dat[1,1],c("b"="b","c"="c"))

  })  
})
```

**server.R (works properly):**

```
library(shinyIncubator)
# library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$new_input<-renderUI({ 
  if (is.null(input$input_file)) {
    return(NULL)
}

progress <- Progress$new(session, min=1, max=10)
on.exit(progress$close())
progress$set(message = 'Calculating',
             detail = 'Please wait...')
for (i in 1:10) {
  progress$set(value = i)
  Sys.sleep(0.05)
}

library(gdata)
dat<-read.xls(input$input_file$datapath,check.names=F)
selectInput("a",dat[1,1],c("b"="b","c"="c"))

  })  
})
```

**ui.R:**

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("a",
               tabPanel("a",
                        sidebarLayout(
                          sidebarPanel(
                            fileInput("input_file","Upload your file:"),
                            htmlOutput("new_input")
                          ),
                          mainPanel(
                            helpText(".")
                          )
                        )
               )
))
```

P.S. An input file is .xls or .xlsx (contents do not matter for reproducing my problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found a solution myself. It appeared that both shinyIncubator and dplyr had a function called Progress. So I have just substituted Progress with shinyIncubator::Progress and the code started working.